# (react-native-deep-link) Triggering app using incoming link issue (playstore url)

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

I built an API which redirects to the respective applink in playstore. On using the API in internet browser, it is not opening the app, rather it's opening the webpage.

I am using below code :

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:host="scoutnex-deeplink.herokuapp.com" android:scheme="https" android:pathPrefix="/scoutnex"/>
</intent-filter>
```

**App.js**

```
componentDidMount(){
   Linking.getInitialURL()
      .then(url => this.handleOpenURL({ url }))
      .catch(console.error);
   Linking.addEventListener("url", this.handleOpenURL);
}
```

If I use something like the below code, the internet browser prompts a request to open an external app on use of the url `peopleapp://people`.

```
<data android:host="people" android:scheme="peopleapp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
>           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
>           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
>           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
>           <data android:host="scoutnex-deeplink.herokuapp.com" android:scheme="https" android:pathPrefix="/scoutnex"/>
>     </intent-filter>
```

uri generated will be **https://scoutnex-deeplink.herokuapp.com/scoutnex**

for

below data intent

```
> <data android:host="people" android:scheme="peopleapp"/>
```

uri generated will be **peopleapp://people**

Please check if you are using router, If yes then you should have people screen in you stack navigator.

At last,

For the best way to test your intent data uri is:

1) Uninstall the existing app if not done yet.

2) sync and build the code again.

3) Call a webview in your app with the uri **peopleapp://people**.

4) It should work.

5) if you are using simulator check the below link provided by android [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#testing-filters)

6) Run this in your terminal(try **adb devices** to test).

```
> $ adb shell am start
>         -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW
>         -d <URI> <PACKAGE>
```

7) URI will be **peopleapp://people**

8) PACKAGE will be your package/application/ name ie..**@string/app_name**.

Hope this helps you. I expect more clarity on you code block. So please comment if you find it confusing.